# joomla comunity builder redirect

Tags: redirect, joomla

i have a site in joomla 3.2 whit CB on.
the site is multi language IT EN, i would like to redirect the user to a specific page after login

but in the module cb_login there are only one Login Redirection URL
any suggest ?

Comment: You could try a template override and manually input a SEF url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have load two cb_login module